# POS using a column (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I would like to extract only nouns from this dataset:

```
        Text1                                      Text2
        
see if your area is affected afte...     public health england have confir...
'i had my throat scraped'.               i have been producing some of our...
drive-thru testing introduced at w...   “a painless throat swab will be t...
live updates as first case confirm...    the first case  in ...

hampton hill medical centre              love is actually just ...
berkshire: public health england a...    an official public health england...
```

I need to apply POS in Text2 in order to extract only ADV. I did as follows

```
ans=[]
for x in 
    tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG="en", TAGDIR='path')
    tags = tagger.tag_text(x)
    ans.append(tags)
    pprint(treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags))
```

but I have not included the column, as I dn not know what I should put (`e.g. df['Text 2'].tolist()`)

What I would need is to extract adverbs from the text and add these in a new array/empty list.
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I prefer spAcy via Google Colab for work like this. I prefer spAcy in general for this kind of task.

If you want to try your hand before seeing my answer, look here.
https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

If you can, you can pip install...

```
        # Please open this notebook in playground mode (File -> Open in playground mode) and then run this block first to download the spaCy model you will be using
    !pip install spacy
    !python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

We are only using Pandas and spAcy here, no need for other packages.

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
```

Recreate the DF

```
list1 = '''see if your area is affected afte... 
'i had my throat scraped'. drive-thru testing introduced at w... 
live updates as first case confirm...'''


list2 = '''hampton hill medical centre             
berkshire: public health england a...   

public health england have confir...
i have been producing some of our...
a painless throat swab will be t...
the first case  in ...
love is actually just ...
an official public health england...'''

df = pd.DataFrame([[list1, list2]], columns = ['Text1', 'Text2'])
```

Grab the string, and initialize spAcy

```
string = df.iloc[0,1]
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

And next, I've written everything into a function here.

```
def list_adv(string):
    '''
    input: list_adv will perform named entity recongition on the input
    return: adv will be a list of all adverbs from the input
    '''
    # have to tell spacy we are doing NLP on the input data
    doc = nlp(string)

    # Blank list to append adverbs to as we search
    adv = []

    # For all named entites in the document
    for token in doc:

      # if the named entity is a adverb, append it
      if token.pos_ == 'ADV':
        adv.append(token.text)

      # if not, skip it
      else:
        continue
      
    # Return the final product
    return adv

adv_list = list_adv(string)
```

The final product will provide a list of adverbs as your question requests!

Comment: Thank you @Sam Lafell. I have found this error: `ValueError: [E167] Unknown morphological feature: 'Person' (2313063860588076218). This can happen if the tagger was trained with a different set of morphological features. If you're using a pretrained model, make sure that your models are up to date:
python -m spacy validate`

Comment: @Val You're not the only one.
First of all, I used Google Colab to run this with no problems but it's more complicated on a local machine.

https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/206
This thread begins to address the problem.

Try running, `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

and then running the above again. If not, let's see what else is going on.